# How to create a calculated column using a lookup table and a formula in R?

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   V1  V2   V3
   3    4   3
   2    4   3
   4    4   3
   4    4   4
   1    4   2
   4    2   4
   4    4   1
   4    4   2
   3    4   1
   4    4   4
   4    4   2
   4    4   2
   2    1   2
   3    2   3
   3    4   3
   3    4   2
   4    4   2
   4    4   4
   2    3   3
   3    4   1
```

I also have a lookup table like this:

```
 V_id   coeff  weight 
  V1   0.82     4.77   
  V2   0.75     4.77   
  V3   0.67     4.77
```

I want to use these values in the lookup table to create a new calculated column in DF1  using

`(V1*coeff+V2*coeff+V3*coeff)/weight`

The final dataframe should look like this.

```
   V1   V2  V3  new_column
   3    4   3   1.566037736
   2    4   3   1.394129979
   4    4   3   1.737945493
   4    4   4   1.878406709
   1    4   2   1.081761006
   4    2   4   1.5639413
   4    4   1   1.457023061
   4    4   2   1.597484277
   3    4   1   1.285115304
   4    4   4   1.878406709
   4    4   2   1.597484277
   4    4   2   1.597484277
   2    1   2   0.78197065
   3    2   3   1.251572327
   3    4   3   1.566037736
   3    4   2   1.42557652
   4    4   2   1.597484277
   4    4   4   1.878406709
   2    3   3   1.236897275
   3    4   1   1.285115304
```

I have to do this for a data frame with 1125 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Updated answer to updated question (data frame has 1,125 columns):

```
df1_V <- as.matrix(df1) # or select the "V" columns using df1[, 1:1125]
df1$new_column <- df1_V %*% df2$coef / df2$weight[1]
```

This is a general solution which will work for any number of columns as long as the columns of **df1** are arranged in the same manner (across the columns of the data frame) as the coef values are ordered (row-wise) in **df2**, *and* the number of columns in **df1** equals the number of rows in **df2**,  that is `ncol(df1_V) = nrow(df2)`.

---

Answer (to original question):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_column = (V1*0.82 + V2*0.75 + V3*0.67) / 4.77)
```

---

```
   V1 V2 V3 new_column
1   3  4  3  1.5660377
2   2  4  3  1.3941300
3   4  4  3  1.7379455
4   4  4  4  1.8784067
5   1  4  2  1.0817610
6   4  2  4  1.5639413
...
```

---

Alternative:

```
df1$new_column <- as.matrix(df1) %*% c(0.82, 0.75, 0.67) / 4.77
```

Comment: I edited my question. My dataframe has 1125 columns. So this would be pretty inefficient. Thank you though.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer. If that doesn't work, or if you have any more edits, let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the first data to long format and then do a group by row number to get the calculated column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = "V_id") %>% 
   left_join(df2)  %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise(new_column = sum(coeff *value)/weight[1]) %>% 
   select(new_column) %>% 
   bind_cols(df1, .)
# A tibble: 20 x 4
#      V1    V2    V3 new_column
#   <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>
# 1     3     4     3      1.57 
# 2     2     4     3      1.39 
# 3     4     4     3      1.74 
# 4     4     4     4      1.88 
# 5     1     4     2      1.08 
# 6     4     2     4      1.56 
# 7     4     4     1      1.46 
# 8     4     4     2      1.60 
# 9     3     4     1      1.29 
#10     4     4     4      1.88 
#11     4     4     2      1.60 
#12     4     4     2      1.60 
#13     2     1     2      0.782
#14     3     2     3      1.25 
#15     3     4     3      1.57 
#16     3     4     2      1.43 
#17     4     4     2      1.60 
#18     4     4     4      1.88 
#19     2     3     3      1.24 
#20     3     4     1      1.29
```

---

In `base R`, we can also do

```
df1$new_column <- c(tcrossprod(df2$coeff, as.matrix(df1)))/df2$weight[1]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L), V2 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L
), V3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

df2 <- structure(list(V_id = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), coeff = c(0.82, 0.75, 
0.67), weight = c(4.77, 4.77, 4.77)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```